# Running old gruntfile grunt-contrib-sass error

Tags: sass, gruntjs

Looking for hours, still no luck.. Tried to run a very old Gruntfile (with imagemin and sass) which used to work. Imagemin is working, sass is not.

The error it throws is:

***Could not find an option named "include-paths".*
*Warning: Exited with error code 64 Use --force to continue.*
*Aborted due to warnings.***

I installed npm. I installed grunt-contrib-sass. I have sass & ruby installed.

where sass gives:
C:\Users..\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass
C:\Users..\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass.cmd

where ruby gives:
C:\Ruby26-x64\bin\ruby.exe

This is a snippet of my Gruntfile, in case you need extra info, I will put it in completely:

```
    sass: {
        peter: {
            options: {
                compress: false,
                sourcemap: 'none'
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'peter/css2/',
                src: ['**/*.scss'],
                dest: 'peter/',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        },
        sots: {
            options: {
                compress: false,
                sourcemap: 'none'
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'sots/css2/',
                src: ['**/*.scss'],
                dest: 'sots/',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
      },
      options: {
        includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
      },
    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
    //require('jit-grunt')(grunt);


    grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['newer:imagemin', 'sass', 'build']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, threw out grunt-contrib-sass and replaced it by node-sass